# javascript click all svg button on page

Tags: javascript

i need to click on the loveheart svg like button using javascript.
i wish to loop and then click all svg button.

here is my code that needs altering.

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  if (button[i].innerHTML === "Follow") {
    button[i].click();
  }
```

}

here is part of the code i got from browser element window

```
<svg width="20" data-e2e="" height="20" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M24 9.01703C19.0025 3.74266 11.4674 3.736 6.67302 8.56049C1.77566 13.4886 1.77566 21.4735 6.67302 26.4016L22.5814 42.4098C22.9568 42.7876 23.4674 43 24 43C24.5326 43 25.0432 42.7876 25.4186 42.4098L41.327 26.4016C46.2243 21.4735 46.2243 13.4886 41.327 8.56049C36.5326 3.736 28.9975 3.74266 24 9.01703ZM21.4938 12.2118C17.9849 8.07195 12.7825 8.08727 9.51028 11.3801C6.16324 14.7481 6.16324 20.214 9.51028 23.582L24 38.1627L38.4897 23.582C41.8368 20.214 41.8368 14.7481 38.4897 11.3801C35.2175 8.08727 30.0151 8.07195 26.5062 12.2118L26.455 12.2722L25.4186 13.3151C25.0432 13.6929 24.5326 13.9053 24 13.9053C23.4674 13.9053 22.9568 13.6929 22.5814 13.3151L21.545 12.2722L21.4938 12.2118Z"></path></svg>
```

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  if (button[i].innerHTML === "Follow") {
    button[i].click();
  }
}
```

but expecting my code to click on all svg button on page.

Comment: So you want to click on every single `<svg>` element?

Comment: yes. click all svg buttons.

Comment: There is no standard web concept of an "SVG button", so you will probably need to define what you mean by this term.  Do you mean any `<button>` that contains SVG inside it?  An SVG that is styled to LOOK like a button, but is actually unrelated to the HTML `<button>` element?  It may also be beneficial to provide a simplified, runnable example that demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: it is tiktok windows software clicking all like button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the `<svg>` elements with `document.querySelectorAll`, loop over them, and dispatch a click event on each one.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('svg').forEach(s => s.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')));
```

Comment: thats not doing it. it ends up clicking another page. its for tiktok likes button